# Get Content-Disposition filename without downloading

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, curl, cmd

I'm currently using

```
curl -w "%%{filename_effective}" "http://example.com/file.jpg" -L -J -O -s
```

to print the server-imposed filename from a download address but it downloads the file to the directory. How can I get the filename only without downloading the file?

Answer (score 1):

Do a `HEAD` request in your batch file:

```
curl -w "%%{filename_effective}" "http://example.com/file.jpg" -I -X HEAD -L -J -O -s
```

This way, the requested file itself will not be downloaded, as per [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4):

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. (...)  This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself.

Note that this will create two files nonetheless, albeit only with the header data `curl` has received. I understand that your main interest is not downloading (potentially many and/or big) files, so I guess that should be OK.

**Edit:** On the follow-up question:

> Is there really no way to get only and only the content-disposition filename without downloading anything at all?

It doesn't seem possible with `curl` alone, I'm afraid. The only way to have `curl` not output a file is the `-o NUL` (Windows) routine, and if you do that, `%{filename_effective}` becomes `NUL` as well.

Comment: Did not work. It got the file downloaded twice instead, one with the filename from the url and the content-disposition filename.

Comment: While it's true that two files are created (both containing a part of the response header), I would be very surprised to see a `HEAD` request download anything. Have you checked the file contents?

Comment: I checked the files, they are actually text files containing the header if opened with a text editor. Is there really no way to get only and only the content-disposition filename without downloading anything at all?

Comment: And by the way the single percent sign does not work in a batch file so I'm using two. You see, I'm working on a batch file, as suggested by one of the tags in this question.

Comment: @user1593556: Would using another command-line tool be a viable alternative?

Answer (score 0):

`curl` gives an error when trying to combine `-J` and `-I`, so the only solution that I found is to parse the header output with `grep` and `sed`:

```
curl "http://example.com/file.jpg" -LIs | grep ^Content-Disposition | sed -r 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/'
```